# Referencia al objeto que se está creando desde dentro de un objeto que se está creando

Tags: c#

Puede que el título sea confuso pero creo que es bastante sencillo de entender cuando leáis lo siguiente.

Tengo 2 clases:

```
public class Persona(){
    public string nombre;
    public int dinero;
    public List<Coche> coches;
}

public class Coche(){
    public string marca;
    public Persona propietario;
}
```

Y al crear una nueva persona hago lo siguiente:

```
Persona nuevaPersona = new Persona(){
    nombre = "Arturo",
    dinero = 10,
    coches = new List<Coche>(){
        new Coche() {
            marca = "SEAT",
            propietario = -> X <-
        }
    }
}
```

¿Cómo hago referencia a la **Persona** que estoy creando desde la propia inicialización del nuevo **Coche**? ¿Es posible hacerlo directamente desde la propia inicialización del objeto? ¿Existe algún keyword como "this", "base" o algo por el estilo?

Sería necesario por ejemplo, si que existe una clase Garaje:

```
public class Garaje(){
    public List<Coche> cochesAlmacenados = new List<Coche>();

    ...
}
```

La cual cobra a los propietarios de cada coche que hay en el garaje, 1€ cada día.

Gracias.

Comment: Creo que básicamente tienes un problema de diseño. Por que almacenar el nombre del propietario dentro del coche, cuando esa persona ya tiene el coche en su coleccion de coches? Ahí hay una duplicidad de información que no entiendo...

Comment: @Pikoh gracias por la respuesta. Puede ser, pero entonces ¿qué forma habría de acceder al propietario del coche directamente si por ejemplo existiese una lista de coches llamada garaje, en la cual has almacenado solo los coches y quisiera acceder al propietario del coche?

Comment: Tal como lo tienes, no es posible(si lo sería,pero es complicarse la vida), dado que no tienes una lista de coches por si misma, sino siempre asociada a un propietario. Tendría mas sentido en ese caso que el propietario se asignase en la clase coche

Comment: Amplia un poco mas el contexto de tu pregunta, como utilizaras esas clases, es decir tienes una lista de autos  y quieres saber quien es su propietario, por ejemplo

Comment: @Pikoh ¿Cómo de complicada? ¡Soy todo oídos!

Comment: @MiguelZarate Ampliado el contexto

Comment: Ok, en ese caso puedes crear una clase persona sin coche propiedad ,  y el auto contiene el nombre del propietario, ahora haras un sistema o solo estas haciendo un ejercicio, es decir registaras autos personas, asignaras un lugar de estacionamiento, el estacionamiento tiene una tarifa,...

Answer (score 0):

Voy a ponerte un ejemplo de como orientaría yo tu problemática.

En primer lugar, la definición de las clases:

```
public class Persona{
    public string nombre;
}

public class Coche{
    public string marca;
    public Persona propietario;
}
```

Como ves, el propietario se almacena en la clase `Coche`, y en `Persona` no hay ninguna referencia al mismo.

Ahora vamos a ver como sería la introducción de datos:

```
//creamos dos IEnumerables para almacenar los datos
List<Coche> coches= new List<Coche>();
List<Persona> personas = new List<Persona>();
    
//Añadimos personas
personas.Add(new Persona(){nombre="Antonio"});
personas.Add(new Persona(){nombre="Juan"});
personas.Add(new Persona(){nombre="Pedro"});
                 
//Ahora añadimos coches, asignadoles el propietario de la lista de personas que tenemos
coches = new List<Coche>(){
    new Coche() {
        marca = "SEAT",
        propietario= personas.Where(x=> x.nombre=="Antonio").SingleOrDefault()
    },
    new Coche() {
        marca = "AUDI",
        propietario= personas.Where(x=> x.nombre=="Antonio").SingleOrDefault()
    },
    new Coche() {
        marca = "BMW",
        propietario= personas.Where(x=> x.nombre=="Juan").SingleOrDefault()
    }
};
```

Por último, vamos a ver como se accedería a los datos. En este primer ejemplo, vamos a obtener los coches que son de "Antonio":

```
    var cochesAntonio= coches.Where(x=> x.propietario.nombre=="Antonio");
    foreach(var coche in cochesAntonio)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(coche.marca);
    }
```

Esto devuelve lo siguiente:

> SEAT
>
> AUDI

En el segundo, vamos a buscar el propietario de un vehículo concreto. Esto es trivial, dado que está almacenado en la propia instancia:

```
    Console.WriteLine(coches.Where(x=> x.marca=="BMW").SingleOrDefault().propietario.nombre);
```

Que lógicamente devuelve:

> Juan

No se si esto cubre todas tus necesidades, pero creo que al menos te puede dar un punto de partida.

P.D. Esto puede hacerse usando el enfoque contrario también, teniendo en `Persona` la lista de los coches que posee dicha persona y dejando la clase `Coche` sin la propiedad `propietario` que no sería necesaria en ese caso. Sería igualmente válido, y la forma de actuar muy similar a la expuesta aqui.